# How to build a raport Top Conversion Paths in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have a problem with build a raport like "Top Conversion Paths" in Google Analytics. Any ideas how can I create this?

I find something like this, but it dosen't work (https://lastclick.city/top-conversion-paths-in-ga-and-bigquery.html):

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(touchpointPath, 'Conversion >.*', 'Conversion') as touchpointPath, COUNT(touchpointPath) AS TOP
FROM (SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(touchpoint,' > ') AS touchpointPath
FROM (SELECT
    *
FROM (SELECT
    fullVisitorId,
    'Conversion' AS touchpoint,
    (visitStartTime+hits.time) AS timestamp
FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE([pro-tracker-id.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2018-10-01'), TIMESTAMP('2018-10-05'))
WHERE
    hits.eventInfo.eventAction="Email Submission success")
    ,
    (SELECT
    fullVisitorId,
    CONCAT(trafficSource.source,'/',trafficSource.medium) AS touchpoint,
    (visitStartTime+hits.time) AS timestamp
FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE([pro-tracker-id.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2018-10-01'), TIMESTAMP('2018-10-05'))
WHERE
    hits.hitNumber=1)
ORDER BY
    timestamp)
GROUP BY
    fullVisitorId
HAVING
    touchpointPath LIKE '%Conversion%')
GROUP BY
    touchpointPath
ORDER BY
    TOP DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you have to modify the query to your needs.

This line needs to be changed to match your specific event action:

```
    hits.eventInfo.eventAction="YOUR EVENT ACTION HERE")
```

The table reference and the dates need to be changed too:

```
TABLE_DATE_RANGE([pro-tracker-id.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2018-10-01'), TIMESTAMP('2018-10-05'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The shared article refers to a [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/legacy-nested-repeated) regarding getting information about the flatten function in BigQuery Legacy SQL.

As far as I know, queries in the new BigQuery UI runs as Standard SQL by default; however, you are able to set the SQL variant by including a [prefix](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#sql-prefix) to your query in the web UI, REST API call or when using the Cloud Client library.